# Get a string after a character in python

Tags: python, list, slice

Getting a string that comes after a `'%'` symbol and should end before other characters (no numbers and characters).
for example:

```
string = 'Hi %how are %YOU786$ex doing'
```

it should return as a list.

```
['how', 'you']
```

I tried

```
string = text.split()

sample = []

for i in string:
    if '%' in i:
        sample.append(i[1:index].lower())
return sample
```

but it I don't know how to get rid of `'you786$ex'`. 
**EDIT**: I don't want to import re

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = 'Hi %how are %YOU786$ex doing'
>>> re.findall('%([a-z]+)', s.lower())
>>> ['how', 'you']
```

[regex101 details](https://regex101.com/r/hPratm/2)

Answer (score 1):

This can be most easily done with `re.findall()`:

```
import re
re.findall(r'%([a-z]+)', string.lower())
```

This returns:

```
['how', 'you']
```

Or you can use `str.split()` and iterate over the characters:

```
sample = []
for token in string.lower().split('%')[1:]:
    word = ''
    for char in token:
        if char.isalpha():
            word += char
        else:
            break
    sample.append(word)
```

`sample` would become:

```
['how', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) (Regular Expressions).

First, create a Regex pattern for your task. You could use online tools to test it. See regex for your task:  https://regex101.com/r/PMSvtK/1

Then just use this regex in Python:

```
import re

def parse_string(string):
    return re.findall("\%([a-zA-Z]+)", string)

print(parse_string('Hi %how are %YOU786$ex doing'))
```

Output:

```
['how', 'YOU']
```